# Outlook 2007 hyperlink and text-indent

Tags: html, css, outlook, outlook-2007

Basically I am trying to hide the text from the hyperlink. I've tried pretty much everything so far, however with not luck on `Outlook 2007`.

```
<a href="http://www.dominos.co.uk/" height="35" width="155" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;
width: 155px; height: 35px; text-indent: -1999px; overflow: hidden; filter:alpha(opacity=0);
zoom: 1;"><font size="35">DOMINOS</font></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Display and overflow are on the Unsupported list for Outlook 2007.  I think in the neutered state of the rendering engine on outlook 2007+, it is safe to say that filter is also not a supported property. See the MSDN on Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook2007,  http://msdn.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx, and code like it's 1989.

What I was getting at is without the display block the text-indent won't work on the anchor tag as it is an inline element.

Comment: You could try changing the color of the font text to white so the text blends into the background.